# De-normalize table or use Joins in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, database-normalization

I need to know what are the tradeoffs of using a denormalized table vs using two separate tables and accessing the data using joins. I am using Entity Framework 4.

In my case I have two tables `Order` and `OrderCategoryDetails`.
I am thinking whether merging these two tables into one single table is better?

- If denormalized, the added columns (`OrderCategory` and `OrderSubcategory` will be will be sparse (could be 100% empty. Will always be at least 50% empty)
- On the other hand, if I keep it as it is, I am worried about frequent join operations being executed (i.e. whenever I am querying for a specific `Order`, I would need information from `OrderCategoryDetails` too.

At present, I have normalized tables and use navigational properties:

- *To access Order Category information from OrderItem instance*

  ```
  OrderItem orderItem = _context.OrderItems.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
  if(2 == orderItem.SalesOrder.Category.OrderCategory){ ...}
  ```
- *To access Order Category information from Order instance*

  ```
  Order order = _context.Orders.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
  if(2 == order.Category.OrderCategory){ ...}
  ```

**This is my schema:**

**Table : Order**

- `ID` (Primary Key)
- Date
- Amount
- ItemCount
- `OrderCategoryInfo` (FK - join with `OrderCategoryDetails` on `OrderCategoryDetails.ID`)

**Table : OrderCategoryDetails**

- `ID` (Primary Key)
- OrderCategory
- OrderSubCategory

**Table : OrderItem**

- `OrderItem ID` (Primary key)
- Order ID (FK - Join with `Order`)

Database used: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: "I am worried about frequent join operations" . . . Does that mean you haven't built tables, loaded sample data, and tested it?

Comment: I have tested it, and there are frequent join operations. I am concerned about it, but I am not sure whether denormalizing is a better idea.

Comment: Ask yourself the question, does every single order require an OrderCategoryDetail?  If the answer is yes then you might be better off de-normalising the data.  If the answer is no you're probably better off keeping it as a seperate table.

Comment: As long as you set up your foreign key association between the tables you shouldn't concern yourself with performance implications of performing a join.  It will only become an issue in pathological situations.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: In other words, normalization and frequent joins are preferable in this case? (50% of the orders do not have an OrderCategory Detail)/

Comment: @escist yes, I would say so.  You shouldn't notice any performance problems if you've got your foreign key association set up correctly.

Comment: I've made this advice on the assumption that you're querying a SQL database.  Is this assumption correct?  What specifically will you be querying against?

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: @escist I've added an answer that summarises my comments and provides a little more advice regarding query performance.  Please give me the accept if you've found this helpful :-)

Comment: @escist: "I have tested it, and there are frequent join operations." The frequency of joins isn't relevant. Speed is relevant. What part is too slow? How fast is "too slow"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My general advice would be to ask yourself the following question; does every single row from the first table require a row from the second table? If the answer is **yes** then you *might* be better off de-normalising the data. If the answer is **no** you're probably better off keeping it as a seperate table.

As long as you set up your foreign key association between the two tables you shouldn't concern yourself with performance implications of performing a join. It will only become an issue in pathological situations.

Based upon your answers in the comments thread, I'd recommend that you should keep the tables separate and set up a foreign key relationship between the two.

If you do get any performance problems further down the line, run a profiler on the problematic SQL and add any indexes that the profiler recommends, but only do this for queries that are used frequently.  Indexes are great for speeding up queries but come at the cost of insert performance, so take care with them.